# Advertencia en sentencia condicional

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una variable `save` para almacenar el directorio que indica dónde guardar una grafica o, en caso contrario y por defecto, tiene el valor `False`.

Después, la siguiente sentencia:

```
if save != False:
    plt.savefig(save + "/" + title + ".png")
```

De modo que si `save` tiene un directorio, se cumple la condición y se guarda la imagen en el lugar indicado y si no, no se guarda la imagen y la ejecución del programa sigue su curso.

Pero me aparece advertencia (uso Spider):

> comparison to False should be 'if cond is not False' or 'if cond:'

¿Hay alguna forma mejor de de resolver el problema?

Comment: `if save is not False:`

Comment: ¿Puedes desarrollar un poco la respuesta?

Comment: `if save is not False:` es mejor que `if save != False:`.

Comment: Si explicas por qué sería de agradecer.

Comment: `if save:` es mejor todavía.

Comment: `if save`creo que no funcionaria. Sólo se cumpliría si `save` tiene el valor `True` y si tiene el valor `True`, entonces no tiene almacenada una dirección.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71229/discussion-between-zhisi-and-goyo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Lo que recibes es una advertencia, que te la da **Spyder**, seguramente por que verifica automáticamente tu código contra la **[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)** que es el documento oficial de estilos de codificación la cual comenta:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
>   is not, never the equality operators. Also, beware of writing if x
>   when you really mean if x is not None -- e.g. when testing whether a
>   variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other
>   value. The other value might have a type (such as a container) that
>   could be false in a boolean context!

Traducción libre:

> Las comparaciones entre singletons como "None" se debe hacer siempre con
>   "is" o "is not", nunca con los operadores de igualdad. También, tenga
>   cuidado al escribir "if x" cuando realmente quiere decir "if not x" --
>   por ejemplo, cuando pruebe si una variable o argumento que por defecto
>   es "None" tiene otro valor. El otro valor podría tener un tipo (por
>   ejemplo, un contenedor) que podría ser falso en un contexto booleano!

Tu construcción `if save != False:` es válida sintácticamente pero no es el estilo "pythonico", la forma recomendada de escribir esta sentencia sería: `if not save:`.

El otro problema que tienes es que está reutilizando una misma variable (`save`) para guardar en un caso un `str`, el directorio que mencionas y caso contrario  un `bool`, el valor `False` si no tienes dicho directorio. No es recomendable hacerlo así, sin embargo si este fuera el caso, lo más sencillo es verificar si el tipo de datos de `save` es una cadena, en cuyo caso tenemos seguridad que la variable tiene el directorio, por ejemplo:

```
if isinstance(save, str):
   print("save tiene el directorio")
```

Pero hay una forma mucho más elegante de resolverlo: en primer lugar, deberemos inicializar la variable `save` como `None`, y además deberemos no modificar el valor en caso de no tener una carpeta como lo estás haciendo ahora:

```
save = None
save = "Carpeta" # Proba comentar esta linea

if save is not None:
    plt.savefig(save + "/" + title + ".png")
```

Nota: Otra forma es inicializar `save` con una cadena en blanco y preguntar por `if save != ""`

Comment: ¿La forma "elegante" que comentas es lo mismo que he hecho yo pero cambiando `False` por `None`  y `!=` por `is not`?

Comment: Si, pero por que digo que es más elegante, lo que estás verificando en castellano sería ¿`save` tiene un valor? esta pregunta es mucho más clara con `if save is not None:` y evitamos una mala práctica que es cambiar el tipo de una variable que es lo que ahora estás haciendo al hacer que sea una cadena en un caso o un booleano en otro.

Comment: Respecto al estilo de codificación PEP 8: _Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.

Also, beware of writing if x when you really mean if x is not None -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value. The other value might have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!_

Comment: Gracias @Zhisi, agrego tu comentario a la respuesta. Saludos.